# Cypress - How to check if a checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

I have some code below to check if a checkbox is checked or not. Even if the checkbox is checked, it says that its not. Why does the code fail and how to fix it?

```
function isChecked(locator : string) : boolean {
 let checked : boolean = false;
 cy.get(locator).then(el){
  if(el.val() === "on"){
   checked = true;//Is actually true when element is checked.
  }
 }
 return checked;//Is actually false when element is checked.
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isChecked(locator) : Promise<boolean>{
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
    cy.get(locator).then((el) => {
      resolve(el.prop('checked'));
    });
  });
}

isChecked('#myCheckbox').then((checked) => {
  if (checked) {
    // Checkbox is checked
  } else {
    // Checkbox is not checked
  }
});
```

Comment: This works well. To make it work in typescript we, should make the return type as Promise<boolean>. thanks

Answer (score 3):

In this case `Promise/resolve` isn't required.

The return value of any `cy.*()` function is a generic `Chainable<Subject>` object, which has a `.then()` method.

```js
function isChecked(locator) : Chainable<boolean> {
  return cy.get(locator).then((el) => {
    return el.prop('checked');
  });
}

isChecked('#myCheckbox').then((checked) => {
  if (checked) {
    // Checkbox is checked
  } else {
    // Checkbox is not checked
  }
})
```